# table partition size?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I have hash partition tables on 11g database which I have to move partition tablespace though, I can't do it because of not enough storage. 
I do know I can drop and recreate tables. I want to move tablespace without any of tough script works.
What I'm wondering is how my partition size is set? 
Can I make it less temporarily after truncate table?
I checked the size of each partition is 8M. 
The schema has 10K partitions.
I'm a oracle newvy. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is your problem that you have many empty tables and partitions that have no data, but still take up a lot of space?  If so, we'll need to know your exact Oracle version number and some sample DDL.  The version number is important because there were significant changes to deferred segment creation in 11.2.0.2.  And we need DDL (from DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL, not just the script you initally used to create the table) to look at all the storage properties, including those inherited from the tablespace.

Comment: 1. Upgrading and enabling deferred segment creation is one possible solution (although "upgrade" is rarely a good answer).  2. Do you really need that many partitions?  Do you have a well-thought out partitioning strategy?  Many people think that "more partitions = faster", but the real equation is very complicated, especially for hash partitions.  Partition-wise joins require specific joins and DOP to be effective.  3. What are your tablespace settings?  Something like `extent management local uniform size 8 M` might waste a lot of space.